# How to toggle child div accordion class when you click outside a nested div?

Tags: javascript

Hopefully, I can explain what I am trying to accomplish. I am working on multiple Accordions. I have created a toggle for each Accordion box.

When I click on the parent div **"accordion"** it should add the active class to the **accordion-content div**

However, I don't want that I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I want to click on the **"accordion__top"** bar and toggle the content class only.

But I have some nesting issues.

Also, how to remove the previous active class if I toggle the next Accordion?

My code:

```
(() => {
    const Accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

    if (!Accordions.length) {
        return;
    }

    const handleAccordion = accordion => {
        const AccordionContent = accordion.querySelector('.accordion__content');
        AccordionContent.classList.toggle('accordion__content--active');
        console.log(accordion);
    };

    Accordions.forEach((accordion, index) => {
        const bindAccordion = handleAccordion.bind(null, accordion, index);
        accordion.addEventListener('click', bindAccordion);
    });
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion__box accordion__box--tertiary">
        <div class="accordion__top">
            <h2 class="accordion__title">Join the collab</h2>
            <span class="accordion__toggle accordion__toggle--primary"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content">
            <p>Coolhaven Collab heeft wil zoveel mogelijk partners in de performance arts aanhaken. Hoe meer hoe beter. <br />
            Ben je coach, heb je een culturele locatie in Coolhaven of geef je bijvoorbeeld dans, zangof theater lessen? Laat je gegevens achter, dan nemen wij contact met je op.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some difficulty understanding what you are trying to achieve.

You mention that you want to click on the **"accordion"** class to toggle the content and the you mention bellow that that you want to click on the **"accordion__top"** to toggle the content.

You don't mention what is not working?

edit, updated snippet

```js
(() => {
    const Accordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__box');

    if (!Accordions.length) {
        return;
    }

    const handleAccordion = accordion => {
      const OtherAccordions = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion__content--active');
        OtherAccordions.forEach((a, index) => {
         a.classList.remove("accordion__content--active");
       });
        const AccordionContent = accordion.querySelector('.accordion__content');
        AccordionContent.classList.toggle('accordion__content--active');
    };

    Accordions.forEach((accordion, index) => {
        const bindAccordion = handleAccordion.bind(null, accordion, index);
        accordion.addEventListener('click', bindAccordion);
    });
})();
```

```css
.accordion__content{
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.accordion__content--active{
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion__box accordion__box--tertiary">
        <div class="accordion__top">
            <h2 class="accordion__title">Join the collab</h2>
            <span class="accordion__toggle accordion__toggle--primary"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content">
            <p>Coolhaven Collab heeft wil zoveel mogelijk partners in de performance arts aanhaken. Hoe meer hoe beter. <br />
            Ben je coach, heb je een culturele locatie in Coolhaven of geef je bijvoorbeeld dans, zangof theater lessen? Laat je gegevens achter, dan nemen wij contact met je op.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion__box accordion__box--tertiary">
        <div class="accordion__top">
            <h2 class="accordion__title">Join the collab</h2>
            <span class="accordion__toggle accordion__toggle--primary"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion__content">
            <p>Coolhaven Collab heeft wil zoveel mogelijk partners in de performance arts aanhaken. Hoe meer hoe beter. <br />
            Ben je coach, heb je een culturele locatie in Coolhaven of geef je bijvoorbeeld dans, zangof theater lessen? Laat je gegevens achter, dan nemen wij contact met je op.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ps sorry about fiddle, had a brainfart

Comment: Sorry, hard to explain. Let's try again. If you click on the "accordion__top" div I would like to toggle a class to the "accordion__content" div only. Now, it toggles the complete accordion box wherever I click but I don't want that. Also, how to remove the previously active box when I switch from one to another? Hopefully, this will help. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I want to loop through all the accordions as the parent class. but only when I click the "accordion__top" I want to toggle the "accordion__content" active class only to prevent closing/opening when you accidentally on the complete block.